# Microsoft Graph giving "The site in the encoded share URI is invalid" when trying to access shared one note item

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-files

I am unable to get the Microsoft graph OneDrive Share API to work with OneNote documents shared from a personal Microsoft account. A URL in the format `https://1drv.ms/u/s!{text}` is generated when sharing a OneNote document generated by a personal Microsoft account. However im unable to use the Microsoft Graph API. The following code is throwing this error:

```
Unhandled exception. Status Code: BadRequest
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: invalidRequest
Message: The site in the encoded share URI is invalid.
```

C# console app code:

```
IPublicClientApplication publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(clientId)
    .WithRedirectUri("http://localhost")
    .Build();

InteractiveAuthenticationProvider authProvider =
    new InteractiveAuthenticationProvider(publicClientApplication, new[] {
        "https://graph.microsoft.com/Sites.ReadWrite.All",
        "https://graph.microsoft.com/Files.ReadWrite",
        "https://graph.microsoft.com/Files.ReadWrite.All"
});

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

var sharingUrl = "https://1drv.ms/u/s!...";
string base64Value = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sharingUrl));
string encodedUrl = "u!" + base64Value.TrimEnd('=').Replace('/', '_').Replace('+', '-');
var shares = await graphClient.Shares[encodedUrl].Permission.Request().GetAsync();
```

As far as i can tell from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/shares_get?view=odsp-graph-online) this should work, any help appreciated.

Comment: How do you create the sharing links?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Ehssan created the sharing link using  the share button in one note under a personal account.

Comment: @Shiva Im trying to programicly get information about the document from the link alone.

Comment: Was able to get it to work using this documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/shares-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#encoding-sharing-urls